# What does `PTS is out of range` mean to VLC?

Tags: vlc-media-player

My VLC (v2.0.6) is showing numerous different errors like these

> main audio output warning: PTS is out of range [...] dropping

and

> main audio output warning: computed PTS is out of range [...] clearing out

These errors result in an audio glitch. What does PTS stand for? How do I resolve this error?

Here is part of my log,

```
[0x7fcef4000978] main audio output warning: computed PTS is out of range (121844), clearing out
[0x7fcef4000978] main audio output warning: PTS is out of range (121844), dropping buffer
[0x7fcef4000978] main audio output warning: computed PTS is out of range (122275), clearing out
[0x7fcef4000978] main audio output warning: PTS is out of range (102275), dropping buffer
[0x7fcef4000978] main audio output warning: computed PTS is out of range (122650), clearing out
[0x7fcef4000978] main audio output warning: PTS is out of range (82650), dropping buffer
[0x7fcef4000978] main audio output warning: computed PTS is out of range (123016), clearing out
[0x7fcef4000978] main audio output warning: PTS is out of range (63016), dropping buffer
[0x7fcef4000978] main audio output warning: computed PTS is out of range (123408), clearing out
[0x7fcef4000978] main audio output warning: PTS is out of range (43408), dropping buffer
[0x7fcef4000978] main audio output warning: computed PTS is out of range (124218), clearing out
[0x7fcef4000978] main audio output warning: PTS is out of range (24218), dropping buffer
[0x7fcef4000978] main audio output warning: computed PTS is out of range (125181), clearing out
[0x7fcef4000978] main audio output warning: PTS is out of range (5181), dropping buffer
[0x7fcef4000978] main audio output warning: computed PTS is out of range (126122), clearing out
[0x7fcef4000978] main audio output warning: PTS is out of range (-13878), dropping buffer
[0x7fcef4000978] main audio output warning: computed PTS is out of range (126720), clearing out
[0x7fcef4000978] main audio output warning: PTS is out of range (-33280), dropping buffer
[0x7fcef4000978] main audio output warning: computed PTS is out of range (127091), clearing out
```

Comment: Which OS and audio driver? I'm guessing a Linux distro and alsa...

Comment: Linux and Pulse.

Answer (score 1):

See [the VideoLan bug tracker](http://trac.videolan.org/vlc/ticket/1134) -- the second result on google for this error message.

You are probably playing a video file with a `PES` stream ([Packetized Elementary Stream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packetized_elementary_stream)). Due to the design limitations of these data, they can't be properly synchronized. So when your video plays at an irregular rate , or when the streams aren't kept in sync by dedicated hardware, the software notices (when it's too late) that they're out of sync, and drops frames in the audio buffer to fix it.

Almost all graphics drivers produce some latency or jitter in the framerate, and even then the piezoelectric quartz crystal driving display timing doesn't match up perfectly with the audio timing crystal, so if the software doesn't have data to keep the audio and video in sync from the data in the video file, you get problems like this.

Note that there is very expensive hardware that *may* be able to keep the streams in sync at a hardware timing level, but usually these systems are for production crews in studios.

Comment: but, I'm playing an oggopus stream -- you can play it yourself if you'd like http://radio.evancarroll.com:8000/stream.opus

Comment: I didn't know we still had crystals in use in modern computers... tsk tsk

Comment: Uhm, [they are](http://superuser.com/questions/253471/how-is-time-measured-in-computer-systems). If you downvoted my answer for talking about quartz crystals in modern PCs, read the answers in the linked question. Get a clue -- there's no reliable way to handle event timing without an extremely regular (periodic) timing mechanism, and quartz crystals do exactly that.

Comment: @Jay - so what is then used, instead of quartz crystals, for timing in PCs?

Comment: I had a similar problem playing some videos on VLC with some bad playing , video did not play smoothly. Smplayer played smoothly the same video.

Comment: As background information: There are other solutions to generate timing pulses using transistors, but they are vary a bit with temperature. Crystals are big, but they simply just work. This is the main reason why we still use them.